# How could an up quark turn into a down quark through practical means?

Tags: standard-model, quarks

How could an up quark turn into a down quark through practical means? When I say practical means I mean not waiting for some natural occurrence like in a star or something like that, but rather something like a particle accelerator.

Answer (score 2):

> How could an up quark turn into a down quark through practical means?

It cannot. Quantum mechanics is not  deterministic, it depends on the probability of the decay, in this case, happening.

Look at [the decay](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html)

[image: uptotdown]

It is a weak decay, and in addition it goes to a virtual W, and the probability of this happening is very small due to the weak vertex and the mass of the W in the propagator. This also means for the decay to happen there should be available energy in order to cover the mass difference, then one can have an up going to a down quark as in:

[image: example]

The stability of protons depends on quantum number conservation laws as the  baryon number. See this for [protons](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/).

In addition, [QCD, the strong force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/color.html) that rules at the quark level, does not allow free quarks, so a quark cannot be free, even using the probability functions.

One can make electron [neutrino beams](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168900285901585), using decays of other particles ( according to the probability of the interaction) but as quarks cannot be free, one cannot have quark beams in any sense.

Comment: While it is true that QCD quarks confine into hadrons, if you smash them hard enough (with a lot higher c.o.m. energy than 200 MeV), you can describe them with high accuracy as independent triplets of quarks.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov sure, theoretically.but the question is about possibility of experimentaly separating them to use them as a beam, which one cannot do with quark jets.